# Optimizing function in Python to handle a big chunk od data

Tags: python, algorithm, function, performance, optimization

I tried solving a problem on HackerRank, called 'Apple and orange', here's the code:

```
def countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges):
    count_apples = 0
    count_oranges = 0
    x = [x for x in range(s, t+1)]
    pos_apple = [apple + a for apple in apples]
    pos_orange = [orange + b for orange in oranges]
    for i in x:
        for j in pos_apple:
            if j == i:
                count_apples +=1
        for l in pos_orange:
            if l == i:
                count_oranges += 1
    print(count_apples)
    print(count_oranges)
```

The code works.
However, when I try submitting it, it passes the first 3 tests and fails the rest with the exception 'Terminated due to timeout'. I checked out the input from one of the tests and it's a huge amount of data to process, you can take a look at the data here:
https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/25220/input03.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1642016820&Signature=J4ypdP0YzRxcOWp%2By5XaD5ITeMw%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

It fails cause it takes like 2 minutes to process the code with the same input via my IDE, but the HackerRank tests are limited to 10 seconds.

I need your help to optimize the code and get it to run faster.

Nested loops seem to be the biggest problem here, but I have no idea what should I replace the with.

Comment: You don't need a nested loop. Just use comparison operators like `<` and `>` to check if an apple or arange is within the boundaries. In Python, you can even do `if s <= j <= t:`.

Comment: SO isn't a great forum for help w/ code challenges.  They'll probably post the "better" answers when the challenge is done.  That said, in almost all of the challenge problems, a nested loop is kiss of death as they will (as you see) load it up with huge data to see if you solved it that way.  Think of the problem differently.  Is there a way to make 1 pass over the data to reduce the time complexity or take advantage of the structure somehow?

Comment: Thanks guys, the `code` if s <= j <= t:  worked so great I don't know how haven't I thought of it earlier.

Comment: It is great that you posted some input data, but how is that used? what are `s`, `t`, `a`, `b`?

Comment: s and t are on the first line, a and b are on the second line, apples are on the third line, and oranges is all the gibberish left. You can check the problem out here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/apple-and-orange/problem?isFullScreen=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not build intermediate lists if you can. If this is really needed (this is not the case for this question) use a generator instead.

And try to do not repeat yourself, factorize with a function when it is possible.

```
def countApplesAndOranges(home_start, home_end, tree_apple, tree_orange, apples, oranges):
    def count_fruits(home_start, home_end, tree, fruits): 
        count = 0
        for fruit in fruits:
            if home_start <= tree + fruit <= home_end:
                count +=1
        return count
    
    print(count_fruits(home_start, home_end, tree_apple, apples))
    print(count_fruits(home_start, home_end, tree_orange, oranges))
```

Comment: `timeit` suggests 12.37 seconds per 1000 runs with provided test data

Answer (score 2):

Checking each apple/orange against each coordinate in range turns your code's runtime complexity into `O(n * a + n * o)` where `n` is the length of the house, `a` is the number of the apples and `o` is the number of oranges. Ideally, your code must run in `O(a + o)`.

Here's a refactored version of your solution:

```py
def countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges):
    count_apples = 0
    count_oranges = 0
    for apple in pos_apple:
        if s <= apple + a <= t:
            count_apples +=1
    for orange in pos_orange:
        if s <= orange + b <= t:
            count_oranges += 1
    print(count_apples)
    print(count_oranges)
```

Comment: `timeit` suggests 12.04 seconds per 1000 runs with provided test data

Answer (score 1):

I think I would `sum()` a couple of list comprehensions as a starting point:

```
apple_hits = sum(
    1 for apple in apples
    if house_min <= apple + apple_tree_origin <= house_max
)
```

One thing that points out to me though is that subtracting apple_tree_origin from the sides of that test should not change it:

```
apple_hits = sum(
    1 for apple in apples
    if house_min - apple_tree_origin <= apple <= house_max - apple_tree_origin
)
```

Now we might observe that `house_min - apple_tree_origin` can be precomputed and the rest my answer falls out as:

```py
def countApplesAndOranges1(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges):
    house_min = s
    house_max = t

    apple_tree_origin = a
    orange_tree_origin = b

    house_min_apples = house_min - apple_tree_origin
    house_max_apples = house_max - apple_tree_origin

    house_min_oranges = house_min - orange_tree_origin
    house_max_oranges = house_max - orange_tree_origin

    apple_hits = sum(1 for apple in apples if house_min_apples <= apple <= house_max_apples)
    orange_hits = sum(1 for orange in oranges if house_min_oranges <= orange <= house_max_oranges)
    return apple_hits, orange_hits
```

With the test data you provided I get `(18409, 19582)`. Hopefully that is correct.

Feel free to `timeit` against other solutions:

```
import timeit

setup = """
with open("apples_oranges.txt") as file_in:
    s,t = list(map(int, file_in.readline().split()))
    a,b = list(map(int, file_in.readline().split()))
    m,n = list(map(int, file_in.readline().split()))
    apples = list(map(int, file_in.readline().split()))
    oranges = list(map(int, file_in.readline().split()))

def countApplesAndOranges_jonsg(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges):
    house_min = s
    house_max = t

    apple_tree_origin = a
    orange_tree_origin = b

    house_min_apples = house_min - apple_tree_origin
    house_max_apples = house_max - apple_tree_origin

    house_min_oranges = house_min - orange_tree_origin
    house_max_oranges = house_max - orange_tree_origin

    apple_hits = sum(1 for apple in apples if house_min_apples <= apple <= house_max_apples)
    orange_hits = sum(1 for orange in oranges if house_min_oranges <= orange <= house_max_oranges)
    return apple_hits, orange_hits
"""

print(timeit.timeit("countApplesAndOranges_jonsg(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges)", setup=setup, number=1000))
```

Comment: `timeit` suggests 8.02 seconds per 1000 runs with provided test data

Comment: Interesting timing works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!

I figured it all out, and used

```
if s <= apple + a <= t:
```

in my code as it's the most simple solution to get rid of the nested loop. It works so good it makes me wonder how haven't I thought of it.

I really like all of your solutions and appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you read any of the previous answers before posting?

Comment: Yes, I read your solution and it's great, thank you! However once I saw the if s <= apple + a <= t: way of solving it, I immediately implemented it into my code to do some testing, and it works totally fine for what I need it for.

Comment: Your solution is really thinking out of the box and takes a step further in simplifying and optimizing the code, I really appreciate the help! I also accepted your answer as it's the best one.